# Calculate average age from date of birth

Tags: sql

I have a database of patients and based on the date of creation I need to find average age of patients month-wise. How can I average the age which I'm already calculating from the date of birth. Here is what I'm doing for calculating the age.

```
select DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birth_Date, GETDATE()) as Age
from ART_NHFC.dbo.Appointment as a
  inner join ART_NHFC.dbo.Patient as p on p.Chart_Number = a.Chart
where MONTH(Appt_Date) = 3 and YEAR(Appt_Date) = 2021
```

Comment: Have you used `AVG()`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific functions used...)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: I was able to do it. LOL, it was pretty simple. Just added AVG function on datediff()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `AVG`?

```
select avg(DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birth_Date, GETDATE())) as AverageAge
from ART_NHFC.dbo.Appointment as a
  inner join ART_NHFC.dbo.Patient as p 
      on p.Chart_Number = a.Chart
where MONTH(Appt_Date) = 3 
  and YEAR(Appt_Date) = 2021
```